# How to produce a list of enum keys/names in groovy

Tags: groovy, enums

I have the following enum in groovy

```
public enum ImageTypes {

    jpg ("image/jpeg"),
    jpeg ("image/jpeg"),
    jpe ("image/jpeg"),
    jfif ("image/jpeg"),
    bmp ("image/bmp"),
    png ("image/png"),
    gif ("image/gif"),
    ief ("image/ief"),
    tiff ("image/tiff"),
    tif ("image/tiff"),
    pcx ("image/pcx"),
    pdf ("application/pdf"),

    final String value

    ImageTypes(String value) {
        this.value = value
    }

    String getValue() {
        return this.value
    }

    String toString(){
        value
    }

    String getKey() {
        name()
    }
}
```

and I want to produce an ArrayList<String> of the keys or the values

What I am currently doing is looping through all the items and building the array list, but I'm thinking there has got to be a simple way to do this...

```
def imageTypes = ImageTypes.values()
def fileExts = new ArrayList<String>()
def mimeTypes = new ArrayList<String>()
for (type in imageTypes) {
    fileExts.add(type.key)
    mimeTypes.add(type.value)
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ArrayList of keys

`ImageTypes.values()*.name()`

ArrayList of values

`ImageTypes.values()*.value`

There are two things to point out here.

1) I'm using the [spread operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_spread_operator) to call an action on each entry in a collection (although this case it's just an array), that's how the `name()` and `value` references are used.

2) I'm calling `name()` with parenthesis (as a method) because (I believe) it is an implicit attribute on the enum, whereas I'm just using the `value` attribute directly from the `ImageTypes` object for the values.

Comment: Worked great! I knew there had to be an easy way in groovy!

Comment: http://www.groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_getters_and_setters You're actually calling the getter method for value. Name doesn't follow the getter/setter format so it can't use Groovy's shorthand

Answer (score 5):

Expanding [@mnd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33287014/4675524)'s answer -

The `Spread Operator` is the best choice, but if you're using Jenkins this won't work as is. To run the `Spread Operator` you will need to add `@NonCPS` in the `Jenkins Pipeline DSL`.

Another way to the list of `enum` keys is to directly use its Enumeration features.

```
ImageTypes.values().collect() { it.name() }
```